# Error Unknown server tag 'tridion:ComponentLink'?

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, dynamic-linking

When i browse my publish page from IIS server then i am getting an error

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

> Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'tridion:ComponentLink'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> {
> "tridion:ComponentLink runat="server" PageURI="tcm:23-20934-64" ComponentURI="tcm:23-20921" TemplateURI="tcm:0-0-0" AddAnchor="false" LinkText="hyperlink text" LinkAttributes=" title="linkComponent" target="_blank" " TextOnFail="true"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up a .NET Web application for SDL Tridion, that involves installing the API Server Role, as explained in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

Installing the API server role involves registering .NET Server Controls which will take care of resolving dynamic links between content items. You will have to add the following DLLs from your installation media `Content Delivery\roles\api\dotNet\` folder to the `bin\` folder of your Web application:

- `netrtsn.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Configuration.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll`
- `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Interop.dll`
- `xmogrt.dll`

More details can be found in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)), because you will have to add the Java `jar` files and Content Delivery configuration files too.

Comment: I am lacking with "Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll". will it affect this?

Comment: @pankaj I think that depends on your configuration, but you should be able to find it in your installation media (I'm assuming you are using version 2013 SP1 here).

Comment: yes @Bart i am using version 2013 sp1.And i create component template with output format "Asp jScript" and Page Template file extension is ".aspx". and i have a schema with RTF field it have one anchor tag with component tcm in href property when i publish this page i got a page with ".aspx" extension when i open this page in browser i got above error.

Comment: @pankaj when you want to output ASP .NET you are better off setting your Template Output Format to `REL`, then the Deployer will insert the correct code. WIth regards to configuration, I meant your Storage and Deployer configuration, please follow the documentation on this, it is all described in there.

Comment: thanks in my application now above error not coming but now i am getting another error. Server Error in '/' Application.
com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: Java.Lang.Exception: com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are missing an association between the prefix "tridion" and the "Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI" namespace. You could add it at the top of every page or just declare it in your web.config like so (applies to all pages then):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    [...]
    <pages>
      [...]
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="tridion" namespace="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI" assembly="Tridion.ContentDelivery" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have done this but still i am getting same error. Can u plz let me know the name of the dll which @Nash is indicating for. I am not getting which dll file he is talking about.

Comment: In the Content Delivery folder you can find pre-built web applications with all required DLLs, jars and web.config - I would suggest comparing your site build with those...

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a dll in your web application, so that your TCDL links get resolved, i forget the name of the dll, you can find that dll on content delivery installation manual